# Is it good to use AspNetCore Http dll in service layer of application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

To give you some context:

I have created a multi tenant web application.

Here, for any request following steps are being done

```
1. Fetch the user information such as ID from HttpContext object
2. Then getting the approprate db name from a common db.
3. Updating the dbContext with the db name
4. And all my repository classes are instantiated based on this updated dbContext
```

First 2 steps are being done in a class library project(service layer) where, in order to get User ID, I have to access HttpContext Object for which AspNetCore.Http.dll is being **manually referenced**.(Took dll and copied in a folder and added to project)

What would be the correct way to do this? Is this a better idea to use NetCore libraries in class library project?

Comment: I generally pass any info that arrived from the request such as `UesrID` from my controller to the service layer methods.

Comment: What if you need to pass other data along with UserID? Lets suppose I need to pass some other ID from Header of the request. Then, all my service methods should be updated.

Comment: That doesn't matter. What you're talking about is actually a bad practice. You're essentially hiding dependencies. Your class needs a user id and some header. Instead of actually making that part of the API, you're trying to just pass in some object the class shouldn't even have knowledge of that just happens to contain those pieces of info (and a lot of other stuff it doesn't need). If it's just the id now, but later you also need a header, *that is actually a breaking change to your API*, and should be handled as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're doing here, but as for `HttpContext`, there's a few points that should help you:

1. It's not enough to have the reference. The fact that you had to manually drop the DLL only adds to the likelihood that this isn't going to work anyways. `HttpContext` only exists within the context of a request pipeline. Regardless of if you can get some bit of code to compile, if it's not running within that pipeline, `HttpContext` will be null and useless to you.
2. Library classes typically should not have dependencies on things like `HttpContext`, anyways. If you need something like a user id in a library class, that user id itself should be passed into the constructor or method (depending on which makes the most sense). The logic of how to obtain a user id from `HttpContext`, is domain knowledge that your class likely shouldn't have.
3. If you are going to use `HttpContext` directly, you should inject `IHttpContextAccessor`. This will require you to add the service in your ASP.NET Core app using `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()`. Once you've done that, you can then get at the current request's `HttpContext` through that accessor instance. If you're outside of the request pipeline, though, it will still be null.